# Object floating in cycles but not eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, shadows

For some reason, objects appear to be floating in cycles, but not in eevee, I'm sure the object is aligned with the flood because the base is clipping through the ground in viewport mode.

Cycles

[image: Cycles]

Eevee

[image: Eevee]

In VPM with overlays on

[image: Viewport]

Comment: Is there a a displacement texture or value plugged into your ground shader? It's possible that the entire floor is being moved down slightly during rendering.

Comment: No displacement on the ground. What's odd is there's a second object in the scene, (the one shown is duplicated from this object) and it doesn't appear floating for some reason. V peculiar

Comment: Consider uploading your blend file so I can have a more thorough look at it.

Comment: I actually think it's an optical illusion caused by the way the light is placed and the camera angle because it doesn't appear in any other angle.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and it was a displacement node in the object's material. Thanks!